# What is a word for someone with no scientific background?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

The word

> **Scientifically Illiterate**:  The condition or quality of being ignorant or unknowledgeable in a particular subject or field related to science.

seems to work, however, it seems a little over the top to call someone an ignorant. Is there another word that does not have this connotation?

Comment: Scientifically-naive?

Comment: How about "He was unschooled in science"? In other words, he was not educated or instructed in science, or he had little or no formal training in science while in school. (see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unschooled). Don

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Layperson

You could call this person a scientific [**layperson**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20layperson):

> a person without professional or specialized knowledge in a particular
> subject.
>
> **synonyms:** layman, nonexpert, nonprofessional, amateur, nonspecialist, dilettante
>
> *"engineering sounds highly specialized to the layperson"*

As per Thomas Francois's request, I'd like to point out that *layperson* isn't a derogatory term. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layperson):

> For instance, an [astronomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomer) is usually skilled in [physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics), [geology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geology), or [engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering). There are, however, a substantial number of amateur stargazers, who are laypersons in the field of [astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomy). Many such laypersons do make discoveries, which can be the subject of much scientific attention, or receive substantial awards recognising the scientific value of their contributions. See, e.g., [amateur astronomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_astronomer) and [citizen scientist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_scientist).

Of course, *how* you use a word is really what decides whether it's derogatory or not, but I think most uses of the term *layperson* are inoffensive.

## Muggle

This is a little bit tongue-in-cheek, but I like to call them [**muggles**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20muggle):

> a person who is not conversant with a particular activity or skill.
>
> *"this video game won't appeal to muggles"*

Of course, the term *muggle* is a [reference to Harry Potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muggle), so it might not be correct for every context.

Comment: Good answer. If you could add some examples to show that the terms are not used in a derogatory way (not always anyway), I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois I've added an excerpt from Wikipedia discussing laypersons in the context of amateur scientists, hopefully that's what you're looking for. I don't think you should delete your answer though, since it provides a related alternative and a discussion on which term should be used. Completely up to you though!